# Microphone needs to boost volume

Tags: microphone

i have been using my Floureon BM-800 microphone for quite a while and trying to find a way to boost the volume of the mic so my friend from skype could hear me properly. is there any solutions to boost the volume of the microphone?
I also did

[image: this]

and its still quiet.

Comment: Remember that you have to be pretty close to the microphone also. Just look at radio hosts or streamers. They have the microphones pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

That microphone uses an XLR cable and requires phantom power. You would have to patch it in through a box that will provide the extra 48V it needs. One such box can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FG795I).

Phantom Power is defined as:

> Phantom power, in the context of professional audio equipment, is DC electric power transmitted through microphone cables to operate microphones that contain active electronic circuitry. It is best known as a convenient power source for condenser microphones, though many active direct boxes also use it. The technique is also used in other applications where power supply and signal communication take place over the same wires.

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power

Comment: But does the phantom power increase the volume?

Comment: Any power will. That's how condenser mics work. http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/microphones/condenser.html